# My Mid 2011 MBP keeps rebooting... Won't boot into safe or recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

This is a new problem as of only a few hours ago... My laptop pretty much lives on a desk so I'm certain it's not a bad SATA cable as was suggested on a different site. I have reset my PRAM (which probably didn't do much on a non POWERPC unit but whatever lol) and tried to boot in all versions of Safe Mode and Recovery... Most don't give any results.. Trying to recover from the internet asks to connect to my wifi, connects successfully but still stays on the grey boot screen afterwards. And the Option-Command R results in a blue screen after the progress bar hits half way.

The only thing I can think of is that something went wrong during the install of Skype this afternoon... I downloaded it from the official site, installed it... But it froze as it tried to open the program. And it's been doing this ever since.

Comment: can you boot from USB ?

Comment: That's a good question... Haven't tried that. Let me look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually had the machine turned completely off?

Comment: The internet recovery wants to download a complete installation image.  They are large so it may take a while

Comment: I let it sit for a day and a half just to give it a rest, then I said nice things to it as I turned it on this morning and lit a candle lol... Sadly it had no affect. I'm on the grey screen now of what I hope is the road to the long download recovery... It showed the spinning earth... Connected to my wifi network... Showed the apple logo with the status wheel upon reset and now is just grey screen... So I hope something positive is happening.

Comment: So I have let it sit on the solid grey screen for nearly 8 hours since starting the internet recovery... Nothing has happened, but it also hasn't randomly rebooted like it does when not in Option-Command R mode (regular command R does nothing which sucks because I'd like to run disk utility) I've never encountered this before, do. You think it could possibly still be downloading..

Comment: Update... So I made a bootable USB of High Sierra on a friend's computer... I am able to get to the choose Start Disc screen... It shows MY SSD boot drive and the USB I made... I selected the USB and it went to the grey screen... Still nothing, I let it sit in the grey screen for over 5 hours... No result.

Comment: Update #2 - I also ran the Apple Hardware test in both the quick. And extended modes and it shows there are no issues on the hardware side (Yay)... I just now used my friends computer to run Target Disc Mode... I deleted Skype because the install of that is what caused the system freeze that started my issues... I also ran the repairs in the disk utility for my SSD and HDD and both came up as OK as well.... It still continues to load and reboot itself never getting to my desktop. I'm running out of ideas and this is my lively hood... Starting to freak out.